# Override core woocommerce class

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have to override following WooCommerce core class methods:

- [`WC_Cart()->get_discounted_price()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1842)
- [`WC_Coupon()->validate_cart_excluded_sale_items()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-coupon.php#L525)

What I'm trying to do is WooCommerce does not allow to have a non-sale product and a sale product in the cart and then apply the coupon code. 
When the following option is checked on coupon `Usage restriction` tab

> Check this box if the coupon should not apply to items on sale. Per-item coupons will only work if the item is not on sale. *Per-cart coupons will only work if there are no sale items in the cart*.

I have to make coupon applied to only non-sale products even if any sale products in the cart. The coupon will only affect non-sale products amount and simply ignore sale products amount.

Now I got workaround with this thing and I have to override with my own custom implementation with above methods. And as you see there are no hooks to work with either.

I also tried this solution without any luck

- [Override woocomerce files from includes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24573928/2706988)

Answer (score 2):

1) There is a hook for the first one:

You can use the `apply_filters`

Their code:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', $price, $values, $this );
```

Your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_discounted_price', function($price, $values, $this)
{
     //return whatever you want
},10,3
);
//*PHP 5.3 and up
```

you can pass whatever function you want into the second parameter of the add_filter function.  Check out the Codex for details.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

2) The second one will be very hacky and probably not recommended:

Though there are no hooks on the `validate_cart_excluded_sale_items()` function, the outcome is dependent up a transient value that you can override (if you are careful to put it back when you are done.

You can adjust the outcome of this functon: `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()`

their code:

```
// Load from cache
    $product_ids_on_sale = get_transient( 'wc_products_onsale' );
...
set_transient( 'wc_products_onsale', $product_ids_on_sale, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30 );
```

what you could do:

store the current `$product_ids_on_sale` from the `get_transient` function

then set it to an empty array

```
set_transient( 'wc_products_onsale', [], DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30 );
```

then set it back when the validation has passed

```
set_transient( 'wc_products_onsale', $your_stored_product_ids_on_sale, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30 );
```

AGAIN, I DO NOT RECOMMEND THIS, BUT I WANTED TO SHOW THAT IT IS POSSIBLE

It sounds like you should just get a better promotion for the sale

Comment: By the time I use the hook `woocommerce_get_discounted_price` the coupon gets apply to the total amount. And the second method doesn't make sense how can I adjust the outcome? Because there is no hook I see near it to adjust outcome. I think it would cause race condition.